# Draw a border around the bright part of the image

Tags: opencv, python

I have an image with a bright center but dark edges. I need to draw rectangle at a certain brightness, so that the darker areas remain outside. Or get the coordinates of this frame. Preferably using OpenCV, the programming language is not important.
[image: input image]
[image: output image]

Comment: The red part in the right side is "bright", is it only the green/yellow brightness what is important? what have you tried so far and what are you block with? I would suggest to try to convert the image in greyscale then cv::threshold to obtain the "brighter" colors and then simply find the rectangle the encloses the white part of the binary image that resulted from the threshold function. However the red part might be to bright, so maybe you might need to use something else to define "brightness". maybe another colorspace?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. This picture is just an example.